# Reading data from other form

Tags: c#-4.0

how can I read data from other Main Form like a simple text for using in Secondary Form?

I used a public variable in main form for assigning but when I call main form the variable is NULL.

Comment: Please show how you call it, also make it static

Comment: Tels tels = new Tels();
            txtName.Text = tels.NameAndSureName();

Comment: tels is a name of main form

Comment: By default a string is NULL. Each time you do "Tels tels = new Tels();", you are creating a brand new form in memory. All of it's values are set to their defaults, include your public string variable. Therefore you are getting NULL in return.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass value to another form and one is to pass it in the `constructor` of the called form and then pass it to a `local/private property`.

Let's say you are in `Form1` and you call `Form2`:

```
 Form2 frmCalled = new Form2("Pass this value");
```

And the `constructor` of your `Form2` will have this now

```
    public Form2(String val)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.passval = val;
    }
```

Which means you have a `property` named `passval` like:

```
  private string passval { get; set; }
```

So, if you want to use it then you could use it now by simply calling the property. If for example a button is click in `Form2` and you want to assign that value now then you will have:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String receivedValue;
        receivedValue = passval;
    }
```

Another way is use a `static` and `public` property from the Parent Form and then call it from the secondary or the called form. Let's say in your `Form1` or the Parent form you will declare like this:

```
  public static string fromParentForm { get; set; }
```

And let's say you are calling the `Form2` or the called form you will do like this:

```
 Form2 frmCalled = new Form2();
 fromParentForm = "Parent Form Value here"; // Put value first in your static property
 frmCalled.Show();
```

In `Form2` could then access that value or property of the `Parent Form` like:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Value from Parent form static property could be access anywhere in the form
        MessageBox.Show(Form1.fromParentForm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use few approaches. One of them(may be not so good practice, but I don't know other purposes of this data.

First create a variable which keep reference of MainForm in SecondaryForm:

```
Private MainForm mainForm;
```

Then create constructor of Secondary form, which take as parameter reference to main form

```
Public SecondaryForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
    this.mainForm = mainForm;    
}
```

Then when you open a secondary form(I assume you opening this from MainForm), create a instance of SecondaryForm with your new constructor:

```
//somewhere in MainForm
SecondaryForm secondaryForm = new SecondaryForm(this);
secondaryForm.Show()    //or ShowDialog()
```

After this inside code of SecondaryForm you can use all public properties/methods of instance od your MainForm